# Table with multiple column (hierarchical table)

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I am trying to draw a table like the following figure [image: hierarchical table].

I found a nearest to the solution of my query is the following [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705153/multi-column-table-with-continuous-vertical-lines). What I found difficult is to add the left most column of my proposed table, that is the column of $K_1$ and $K_2$. Any kind of help is appreciable.

Comment: Is it important to have doubled vertical and horizontal lines? Is there an overall target width for the table?

Comment: @Mico I think that is not a problem if you use `\bottomline` two times (for horizontal line) and `||` (for vertical line). Double horizontal line can be extend to $K_1$ column.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of 'X' column type
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped "look"
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l | l | C | C | C | C || C | C | C | C }
\hline
  &   & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{A} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B} \\
\cline{3-10}
  & p & I & II & III & IV & I & II & III & IV \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$K_1$} & 
    a & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\ \cline{2-10}
  & b & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\ \cline{2-10}
  & c & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\ \cline{2-10}
  & d & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\
\hline\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$K_2$} & 
    a & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\
  & b & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\
  & c & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\
  & d & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{} \\  
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's what a solution that (a) employs the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package and (b) does away with all vertical rules and all doubled rules might look like. As the old saying goes, there's no arguing about taste. Speaking for myself, though, I find this table to be far easier on the eye than the one with lots of horizontal and vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} ll *{8}{C} @{}}
\toprule
  &   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-10}
  & p & I & II & III & IV & I & II & III & IV \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{$K_1$} & 
    a  \\ 
  & b  \\ 
  & c  \\ 
  & d  \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{$K_2$} & 
    a  \\
  & b  \\
  & c  \\
  & d  \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice solution Mico. One minor question, If I use `\bottomrule`and `\toperule` instead of `\hline` then lines are breaking. Can I remove that?

Comment: @Cantor_Set - To quote from section 2 of the user guide of the `booktabs` package: "You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times: 1. Never, ever use vertical rules. 2. Never use double rules." (Oops, but your table violates both rules...) In short: If you want to use the macros of the `booktabs` package, don't use vertical rules. The corollary: If you must use vertical rules, don't use the macros of the `booktabs` package.

Comment: @Cantor_Set - Please also see the addendum I just posted. It implements the two main guidelines of the the `booktabs` package: (a) no vertical rules and (b) no double rules.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `tabularray`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={*{10}{X[c,m]}},
        width=\linewidth,
        cell{1}{2} = {r=2,c=1}{c},
        cell{1}{3,7} = {r=1,c=4}{c},
        cell{3,7}{1} = {r=4,c=1}{c},
        hline{2} = {3-Z}{solid},
        hline{1,3,7,Z} = {solid},
        hline{7} = {2}{-}{solid},
        vline{2,3,7} = {solid},
        vline{4-Y} = {2}{solid},
        vline{7} = {2}{-}{solid},
        hline{4-6} = {2-Z}{solid},
%       hline{8-10} = {2-Z}{solid}
        }
        & p & A & & & & B & & & \\
        &       & I & II & III & IV & I & II & III & IV \\
        $k_1$   & a &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
                & b &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
                & c &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
                & d &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
        $k_2$   & a &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
                & b &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
                & c &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
                & d &    &     &    &   &    &     &    \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Wow, nice solution with minimal package usage.

Comment: You can change the hline and vline width using something like `hline{2} = {3-Z}{solid,1pt},` in the specifications of the hline (or vline)